# Meaning of 「臨徴す」?

Tags: words

I'm currently reading the novel 「学生街の殺人」by 東野圭吾, and on page 230 the following sentence is spoken:

```
「商店街の会費を臨徴して作ったんだろう？まさしく背水の陣だな」
```

The character is referring to all shop owners of the district having pooled together money to set up a big Christmas tree in the vicinity in hopes of more customers.

For some reason, I cannot determine the meaning of 「臨徴す」.　It would make sense to me if it was only 「徴す」, but why is a 「臨」prepended in this case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it's short for [臨時徴収]{りんじちょうしゅう}... (I have never heard it, though...)

Comment: うわっ、２７秒負けたわ。かなんのお。

Comment: でも、早くても詳しくなかったので・・・ううう・・・

Comment: @TokyoNagoya えっ、なんでこっちがaccept??

Answer (score 4):

「[臨徴]{りんちょう}」 is the shortened form of 「[臨時徴収]{りんじちょうしゅう}」; therefore, it may not be found in the dictionary.  There should be enough information, context or background story in your book that would suggest that it stands for 臨時徴収.  Otherwise, 臨徴 would not have been used.

「臨時徴収」, needless to say, means "temporary or special collection (of a fee)".

Comment: 結局「収める」みたいな意味だと文脈でなんとか察したんですが、ネット検索でも辞書でも出てこなくてびっくりしました。ご回答ありがとうございます。